# HOWTO split response time into dns name lookup, wait, transfer time in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, response-time

I would like to know if I can get a breakdown of response times in JMeter load tests. E.g. when I use curl I can get the breakdown of each response time by specifying curl format like so,

```
\n
            time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}\n
               time_connect:  %{time_connect}\n
            time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}\n
           time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}\n
              time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}\n
         time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}\n
                            ----------\n
                 time_total:  %{time_total}\n
\n
```

and then making the actual curl call like so,

`curl -w "@curl-format.txt" "http://some.api/call"`

As you can see this gives me the breakdown in terms of time spent doing a DNS Name resolution, connecting with the server, transferring response form server to the client etc.

Is it possible to get something similar in JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have at least found a way to get what I want, partially.

In Jmeter I can collect the `Connect` time, which is a combination of DNS lookup, handshake & connection.

If someone has a better answer, would be happy to know it.